# Apply scope to promise .then() functions from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm new to AngularJS.

I'm calling a service from a controller that is communicating with a webservice. the service returns a promise to the controller. Now I want to apply the data that is available on the success function of the promise to $scope. How can I achieve this? I already tried to do $scope.$apply() on the service call or the promise success function, but this just gives me errors.

Controller:

```
angular.module('home')
    .controller('HomeCtrl',
    ['$scope', 'myService',
        function ($scope, myService) {

            $scope.data = [];

            $scope.getData = function () {
                // this is triggered via btn click
                myService.getSomeData(reqData)
                    .then(
                    function success(res){
                        // apply res.data to $scope.data ?
                    },
                    function failure(err){
                       //error handling
                    }
                );
            }
        }]);
```

Service:

```
angular.module('myService')

    .factory('myService', ['$http', '$rootScope',
        function ($http, $rootScope) {
            return {

                generalWebServiceProxy: function (webserviceName, data, xml) {
                    // do some xml stuff, settings header etc

                    return $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: URL,
                        headers: headers,
                        data: data
                    });
                },

                getSomeData: function (data) {
                    return this.generalWebServiceProxy('WSName', data, true).then(/* do something here and return data*/);
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http returns a promise where the server response is resolved. That response object contains things like status, data, header, etc.. etc...

Your service should handle these responses itself. So that the method `setSomeData` resolves to that *data*. Right now, it's resolving to the server response which isn't very useful for your directive.

```
generalWebServiceProxy: function (webserviceName, data, xml) {
   // this method is return a promise
   return $http({...});
},

// this method uses "promise chaining"
getSomeData: function (data) {
     return this.generalWebServiceProxy(
     'WSName',
     data,
     true).then(function(response) {
         if(response.status == 200) {
            return response.data;
         }
         throw new Error("Unexpected response:"+response.status);
    });
}
```

In the above code I've done something called *promise chaining*. That's where the return value of a *then* mutates the resolve value. So the *next* promise then call will have `response.data` as the parameter.

Later in your directive you can use the promise returned by the service as a regular promise. It just resolves to the `data` in the response.

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    myService.getSomeData(reqData)
        .then(function success(data) {
            // ^^ data is actually the value `response.data` from the service
        });
}
```

### What about error handling?

There are two kinds of errors with $http. There are HTTP errors like unable to resolve host, failure to connect or timeouts, and then there are response errors. Such as content missing or content not found. Some of these can be handled with the promise failure callback, and some are successful responses that you don't want.

So in my example I restrict success to mean an HTTP 200 response. You might want to check that the *data* given back is what you were expecting (for example, is it an array?).

I've found it better to handle errors using a HTTP interceptor. Otherwise you have to implement error handles in every directive that uses the service.

Comment: My service is already doing response and error handling. There is already alot of promise chaining happening. I just simplified the example because this code is out of scope. You're giving a very detailed answer about promise chaining and error handling that was not part of my question. You said "Later in your directive you can use the promise returned by the service as a regular promise" That is my actual question if I do $scope.data = data on the success fn on the controller, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined(…)

Answer (score 1):

$http is a promise and over here you not returning the promise and using it as a promise in the controller.

Modified Service:

```
angular.module('myService')

    .factory('myService', ['$http', '$rootScope',
        function ($http, $rootScope) {
            return {

                generalWebServiceProxy: function (webserviceName, data, xml) {
                    // do some xml stuff, settings header etc

                    return $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: URL,
                        headers: headers,
                        data: data
                    });
                },

                getSomeData: function (data) {
                    return this.generalWebServiceProxy('WSName', data, true);
                }
            }
        }]);
```

And have the controller as is and update the $scope variable within success block.

Comment: You don't know what I was returning in the .then() part (because I left it out). I always thought it doesn't matter if the return value is async or sync on a promise chain. Doesn't matter - even if a left out the .then functions on the service, $scope is not accessible on the controller on the success function. Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined(…)